# OptionMenu command argument changing when function called

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and I'm trying to create an OptionMenu that updates a frame when an option is chosen from the menu. The issue I'm running into is that the frame I'm passing as an argument to the `select` function is changing to the menu selection. Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Here is an example code. When I print `self.display` I get the expected value of .!frame, but after I pass it as an argument to `select` and print I get the value of the option chosen from the drop down menu.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class menu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, display, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.display = display

        menu_frame = tk.Frame(self.parent)

        self.default_val = tk.StringVar()
        self.default_val.set("Default")

        print(self.display)
        menu = tk.OptionMenu(menu_frame, self.default_val, "A", "B", "C", command=lambda arg=self.display: self.select(arg))
        menu.pack()
        
        menu_frame.pack()
        
    def select(self, frame):
        print(frame)
        selection = self.default_val.get()
        self.default_val.set("Default")


app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("400x200")
display_frame = tk.Frame(app)
display_frame.pack()

menu(app, display_frame)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not really related to your problem but why are you inheriting from `tk.Frame`? Also the line `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)` is useless because you never use that frame

Comment: There's no reason other than I'm still figuring out classes in tkinter, I'm sure my GUI project is riddled with stupid mistakes like this

Comment: ```command=lambda x: self.select(self.display)```, try this?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, that works. Can I ask why that syntax works but not ```command=lambda arg=self.display: self.select(arg)```?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve by passing a frame to a function that you don't actually use? The command callback for an `OptionMenu` requires one argument, which is the currently selected choice. That you set `self.display` as a default argument for that doesn't mean it changes your frame, or uses that, as it will be overwritten by the choice value that it needs to pass anyway.

Comment: I stripped out everything from the code to only focus on the piece that was causing the problem. Ultimately the real function will update the passed-in frame based on the selection from the drop down menu, by passing that frame as an argument to different classes. I just removed that piece from the example.

Comment: If the frame you're going to change is based on the choice from the OptionMenu, you don't need to pass the frame yourself. Also, the way you've done it now you've hardcoded the frame, so the same frame will always get passed to the function.

Comment: `lambda arg=x: ...` will assign the default value `x` to `arg` if the `lambda` is executed without specifying `arg`.  However the callback for `command` option of `OptionMenu` will be passed the selected value when it is executed, so the default value will not be used.